# HTML5 Canvas follow object

Tags: html, canvas, camera, html5-canvas, viewport

I'm making an HTML5 game and I'm new to this, My issue is that I'm making a 2D game and
 I have a background that is bigger than my canvas.

I need that when my main object moves the camera moves with it so new background parts appear? But also that the rest of the objects disappear when required.

A little example will be

http://www.realmofthemadgod.com

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16919601/2252829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11406488/577306) from Simon Sarris:

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/oberto/4URBP/)

*Ignore the line below - posting a jsFiddle link requires accompanying code - which is too long to post!*

```
var showFiddle = true
```

Comment: +1 for nice starting scrolling-game template in your Fiddle.  Also, thanks for making me smile with var showFiddle=true. :)

Comment: haha, thanks. But credit goes to Simon Sarris for creating that.